# Chrome Extension: Which Api to get ratings?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have written a chrome extension which uses the google+ - api to collect some basic information about the user.

I now would like to display something like "Thank you for rating this extension on the chrome web store".

How can I find out if a user rated my extension? Which Api do I have to use? The "Chrome Web Store API" seems to be the wrong one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no public API for getting Chrome Web Store information or ratings.

Edit: There is a [Chrome Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index), however it's current implementation is designed for automated extension updating/publishing.

Comment: Well. Then that's the reason why I searched without success :) Thanks